MARS MIPS Assembly Code for Tree Search Algorithms
I'm working on a project, and I need help with my MIPS assembly code. The project requires implementing depth-first search (DFS) and breadth-first search (BFS) algorithms for binary trees represented in two different formats, along with conversion procedures between these representations. However, my code doesn't seem to produce any output. Can someone help me debug this? Below is my code:
Project Requirements
Depth-First Search (DFS): Search for a value in a binary tree and return the level where the element is found, or -1 if not found.
Breadth-First Search (BFS): Search for a value in a binary tree and return the level where the element is found, or -1 if not found.
Conversion Procedures:
Convert from Representation 1 to Representation 2.
Convert from Representation 2 to Representation 1.
BFS Implementation:
Perform BFS on both representations of the tree.
``

.data
arraylist_data: .space 400
arraylist_size: .word 0
tree_rep1: .word 4, 9, 10, 10, 15, 2, 3
tree_rep2: .space 28
search_value: .word 10
queue_data: .space 100
queue_front: .word 0
queue_rear: .word -1
queue_size: .word 0
result_msg: .asciiz "Value found at level: "
not_found_msg: .asciiz "Value not found.\n"
dfs1_msg: .asciiz "DFS (Rep 1): "
dfs2_msg: .asciiz "DFS (Rep 2): "
bfs1_msg: .asciiz "BFS (Rep 1): "
bfs2_msg: .asciiz "BFS (Rep 2): "


.text
.globl main

# ArrayList Operations
create_arraylist:
    sw $zero, arraylist_size
    jr $ra

append_arraylist:
    lw $t0, arraylist_size
    sll $t1, $t0, 2
    la $t2, arraylist_data
    addu $t2, $t2, $t1
    sw $a0, 0($t2)
    addi $t0, $t0, 1
    sw $t0, arraylist_size
    jr $ra

get_arraylist_size:
    lw $v0, arraylist_size
    jr $ra

# Queue Operations
create_queue:
    li $t0, 0
    sw $t0, queue_front
    li $t0, -1
    sw $t0, queue_rear
    sw $zero, queue_size
    jr $ra

enqueue:
    lw $t0, queue_size
    li $t1, 100
    beq $t0, $t1, enqueue_full
    lw $t0, queue_rear
    addiu $t0, $t0, 1
    li $t1, 100
    rem $t0, $t0, $t1
    sw $t0, queue_rear
    la $t1, queue_data
    sll $t2, $t0, 2
    addu $t1, $t1, $t2
    sw $a0, 0($t1)
    lw $t0, queue_size
    addiu $t0, $t0, 1
    sw $t0, queue_size
    jr $ra

enqueue_full:
    jr $ra

dequeue:
    lw $t0, queue_size
    beqz $t0, dequeue_empty
    la $t0, queue_data
    lw $t1, queue_front
    sll $t2, $t1, 2
    addu $t0, $t0, $t2
    lw $v0, 0($t0)
    addiu $t1, $t1, 1
    li $t2, 100
    rem $t1, $t1, $t2
    sw $t1, queue_front
    lw $t0, queue_size
    addiu $t0, $t0, -1
    sw $t0, queue_size
    jr $ra

dequeue_empty:
    jr $ra

is_queue_empty:
    lw $t0, queue_size
    beqz $t0, is_empty
    li $v0, 0
    jr $ra

is_empty:
    li $v0, 1
    jr $ra

# Conversion Procedures
convert_rep1_to_rep2:
    addi $sp, $sp, -12
    sw $ra, 8($sp)
    sw $s0, 4($sp)
    sw $s1, 0($sp)
    jal create_arraylist
    move $s0, $a0
    li $a0, 0
    move $s1, $a1
    jal convert_helper_1_to_2
    la $t0, arraylist_data
    move $t1, $s1
    lw $t2, arraylist_size
    li $t3, 0
copy_loop:
    beq $t3, $t2, copy_done
    sll $t4, $t3, 2
    addu $t5, $t0, $t4
    lw $t6, 0($t5)
    sw $t6, 0($t1)
    addi $t1, $t1, 4
    addi $t3, $t3, 1
    j copy_loop
copy_done:
    lw $s1, 0($sp)
    lw $s0, 4($sp)
    lw $ra, 8($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 12
    move $v0, $s1
    jr $ra

convert_helper_1_to_2:
    blt $a0, 0, return_helper_1_to_2
    sll $t0, $a0, 2
    addu $t0, $s0, $t0
    lw $t1, 0($t0)
    move $a0, $t1
    jal append_arraylist
    sll $t3, $a0, 1
    addi $t3, $t3, 1
    addi $t4, $t3, 1
    lw $t6, arraylist_size
    blt $t3, $t6, process_left
    j check_right
process_left:
    move $a0, $t3
    jal convert_helper_1_to_2
check_right:
    lw $t6, arraylist_size
    blt $t4, $t6, process_right
    j return_helper_1_to_2
process_right:
    move $a0, $t4
    jal convert_helper_1_to_2
return_helper_1_to_2:
    jr $ra

convert_rep2_to_rep1:
    addi $sp, $sp, -16
    sw $ra, 12($sp)
    sw $s0, 8($sp)
    sw $s1, 4($sp)
    sw $s2, 0($sp)
    move $s0, $a2
    move $s1, $a0
    move $s2, $a1
    li $a0, 0
    li $a1, 0
    jal convert_helper_2_to_1
    lw $s2, 0($sp)
    lw $s1, 4($sp)
    lw $s0, 8($sp)
    lw $ra, 12($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 16
    move $v0, $s2
    jr $ra

convert_helper_2_to_1:
    blt $a0, $s0, valid_index
    j return_helper_2_to_1
valid_index:
    blt $a0, 0, return_helper_2_to_1
    sll $t0, $a0, 2
    addu $t0, $s1, $t0
    sll $t1, $a1, 2
    addu $t1, $s2, $t1
    lw $t2, 0($t0)
    sw $t2, 0($t1)
    addi $a0, $a0, 1
    addi $a1, $a1, 1
    jal convert_helper_2_to_1
    addi $a0, $a0, 1
    sll $t3, $a1, 1
    addi $a1, $t3, 1
    jal convert_helper_2_to_1
return_helper_2_to_1:
    jr $ra

# Depth-First Search
dfs_recursive:
    blt $a1, 0, dfs_not_found
    sll $t0, $a1, 2
    addu $t0, $a0, $t0
    lw $t1, 0($t0)
    bne $t1, $a2, check_left
    move $v0, $a3
    jr $ra
check_left:
    addi $t3, $a1, 1
    move $a1, $t3
    addi $a3, $a3, 1
    jal dfs_recursive
    move $t4, $v0
    bne $t4, -1, return_dfs
    addi $t5, $a1, 1
    sll $t5, $t5, 1
    addi $t5, $t5, 1
    move $a1, $t5
    jal dfs_recursive
    move $t6, $v0
    move $v0, $t6
    jr $ra
dfs_not_found:
    li $v0, -1
    jr $ra
return_dfs:
    move $v0, $t4
    jr $ra

# Breadth-First Search
bfs:
    addi $sp, $sp, -16
    sw $ra, 12($sp)
    sw $s0, 8($sp)
    sw $s1, 4($sp)
    sw $s2, 0($sp)
    la $s0, queue_data
    move $s1, $a0
    move $s2, $a2
    jal create_queue
    lw $t0, 0($s1)
    move $a0, $t0
    jal enqueue
bfs_loop:
    jal is_queue_empty
    bnez $v0, bfs_not_found
    jal dequeue
    move $t1, $v0
    lw $t2, 0($s1)
    beq $t1, $t2, bfs_found
    addi $a0, $a0, 1
    sll $t3, $a0, 2
    addu $t4, $s1, $t3
    lw $t5, 0($t4)
    move $a0, $t5
    jal enqueue
    j bfs_loop
bfs_found:
    lw $s2, 0($sp)
    lw $s1, 4($sp)
    lw $s0, 8($sp)
    lw $ra, 12($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 16
    jr $ra
bfs_not_found:
    lw $s2, 0($sp)
    lw $s1, 4($sp)
    lw $s0, 8($sp)
    lw $ra, 12($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 16
    li $v0, -1
    jr $ra

# Main Program
main:
    la $a0, tree_rep1
    li $a1, 7
    lw $a2, search_value
    li $a3, 0
    jal dfs_recursive
    move $t0, $v0
    la $a0, dfs1_msg
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    move $a0, $t0
    li $v0, 1
    syscall
    la $a0, not_found_msg
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    la $a0, tree_rep2
    li $a1, 7
    lw $a2, search_value
    li $a3, 0
    jal dfs_recursive
    move $t0, $v0
    la $a0, dfs2_msg
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    move $a0, $t0
    li $v0, 1
    syscall
    la $a0, not_found_msg
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    la $a0, tree_rep1
    lw $a2, search_value
    jal bfs
    move $t1, $v0
    la $a0, bfs1_msg
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    move $a0, $t1
    li $v0, 1
    syscall
    la $a0, not_found_msg
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    la $a0, tree_rep2
    lw $a2, search_value
    jal bfs
    move $t1, $v0
    la $a0, bfs2_msg
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    move $a0, $t1
    li $v0, 1
    syscall
    la $a0, not_found_msg
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    li $v0, 10
    syscall



``

Mars Messages:
Assemble: operation completed successfully.
Error in : invalid program counter value: 0x00000000
Step: execution terminated with errors.

Zero is indeed a bad program counter value.  You need to find out why your program is jumping to zero.  It is most likely a jr $ra instruction.  Use the debugger to find the offending instruction, then the reason that this instruction is being given a bad address to jump to.

For example convert_helper_1_to_2 is not preserving $ra.
